# eventDrop fullcalendar hour current

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I am using the eventDrop function fullCallendar.

The problem occurs when I click the event that wish to upgrade to another day / schedule and this taking the current time of ...

For example: I have an event in the calendar day: 09.10.2016 time 10:00. I move it for the day 09/11/2016 15:00 hour, but WHAT I get in my alert is current time.

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {

                    var start = moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm');


                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/updateJson?cod=' + event.id,
                        data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&id=' + event.id,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (json) {
                            console.log(json);
                            alert('title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&id=' + event.id);
                        }
                    });
                },
```

I want to click on the agenda 10:00 and that value go to "start" variable and not get the local time.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new moment `start` with variable `start`. That does not make sense. If I understand you correctly, you want your `start` variable to have the date and time where you drop your event, not the current date. So change your variable assignment to the following.

```
var start = event.start;
```

This will assign `start` as the time where the event is dropped.

Edit: this date will be in UTC. To get your date formatted do the following.

```
var start = moment(event.start).format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: did not work. My alert shows a sequence of numbers. Ex:  `start=1473354000000`

Comment: That is a UTC timestamp. That is how moments will be stored in the database. If you want them to be displayed or stored in your local time then you must format the date.